# Atoms mapping reaction RDKit

Tags: python-3.x, rdkit

After applying a simple reaction I am getting the following warning message:

```
product 1 has no mapped atoms.
```

I am guessing that has something to do with atoms mapping after reaction, but I am including and index to the smarts formula to avoid this allowing RDKit to know what to do with the reactants I provide, but I cannot figure  out what this warning means.

My approach so far:

```
rxn = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('[Ch:1]-[C+1:2]>>[C:1]=[C+0:2].[H+]')
ps = rxn.RunReactants((Chem.MolFromSmiles('C/C1=C\\C[C@H]([C+](C)C)CC/C(C)=C/CC1'),))
```

Which leads me to the following warning:

```
product 1 has no mapped atoms.
```

When checking products and its smiles I can't see anything strange that can be related to the warning.

```
Chem.MolToSmiles(ps[0][0])
Out[16]: 'CC(C)=[C@H]1C/C=C(\\C)CC/C=C(\\C)CC1'
Chem.MolToSmiles(ps[1][0])
Out[17]: 'C=C(C)[C@H]1C/C=C(\\C)CC/C=C(\\C)CC1'
```

Any hints?

Comment: The reason is that your product [H+] is not mapped in the reactants, whereas your other reactants are mapped (:1, :2). If you remove your [H+] product from the reaction you can see that the warning is not raised

Comment: Yes, I just realized. Thank you very much Oliver :)